# How to update dictionary from a tuple (or list of 2)

Tags: python, dictionary

I thought it would be possible to update an existing dictionary as follows:

```
nameValuePair = 'myKey=myValue'
d.update(nameValuePair.split('='))
```

However I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#98>", line 1, in <module>
    d2.update(item.split('='))
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

I looked at some other StackOverflow questions/answers on this topic, which made me think this was possible. I must be missing something basic...

Comment: By the way, you probably want to use `split('=', 1)` here to guarantee that the `split` always returns a pair, even if the right hand side contains an `=`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error message already gives you a hint: Each item in the sequence you pass must have a length of 2, meaning it has to consist of a key and a value.

Therefore you have to pass a tuple (list, sequence,...) of 2-tuples (-lists, -sequences,...):

```
// the value passed will be ((myKey, myValue), )
d.update((nameValuePair.split('='), ))
//       ^                        ^ ^
// creates a tuple of 1 element
```

Alternatively you could do:

```
key, value = nameValuePair.split('=')
d[key] = value
```

Comment: Great, thanks for explaining that. I didn't understand error message at all!

Comment: Coming back to this: something I still don't understand. Python docs says: _update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two). If keyword arguments are specified..._  This code works: `d.update([nameValuePair.split('=')]`, because it is using sequence of sequence of length 2, which is logical to me. The solution you gave, also works, but I don't understand why. It is using a Tuple of length 2, which has first element as sequence of length 2. What is the Tuple's second element?

Comment: You are right, one could just use a list as well... I don't know what I was thinking. Anyways, the outer tuple is not of length two, it's of length one. `(something, )` creates a one-tuple. Python is smart enough to notice that the second element does not exist. You need a comma to create a tuple because in `(something)`, the `()` would be interpreted as grouping operator instead. Just do `a = (42, ); print len(a)` and see for yourself :)

Comment: "Anyways, the outer tuple is not of length two, it's of length one. (something, ) creates a one-tuple." I'm still confused about the semantics - what exactly does the "one-tuple" represent as an argument?

Comment: It's a tuple with one element. Like a list with one element, only that you cannot add or remove element from the tuple, it's immutable. Think about a tuple as a list that you cannot change.

Answer (score 1):

```py
tp = ('k', 'val')
d.__setitem__(*tp)
```