# "dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required"

Tags: python, dictionary

When trying to update a dictionary with a tuple, I encountered the error:

`>>> dict1.update(("stat",10))`

`ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 4; 2 is required`

When in reality this shouldn't be happening. From the python docs,

> update() accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two).

This makes no sense, since the tuple i supplied clearly has length 2.

`>>> len(("stat",10))`

`2`

What is going on? Is this a bug that isn't resolved yet? Running Python 3.8.0.

Or was this due to the fact that my dictionary is empty? Tried this with other strings and values, same problem.

Comment: I am aware of that fix. But I don't want to build a temporary dictionary just to deal with this problem. Building tuples are just faster. I am also curious of the origins of this problem/ bug.

Comment: Try `dict1.update({"stat": 10})`

Comment: The problem is that it wants an iterable of pairs, but you're passing a pair directly; one level of the data structure is missing. You need to put that level of data structure in, either `dict1.update((("stat", 10),))`, which is a _tuple_ of pairs, or `dict1.update([("stat", 10)])`, which is a _list_ of pairs.

Comment: the length it found is the length of the string "stat"

Answer (score 3):

The documentation said you need an ***iterable*** of key value pairs. A single tuple is not an iterable of key value pairs, either a list or tuple of tuples will do.

```py
dict1.update([("stat", 10)])
```

Comment: Which is faster? a new, temporary dictionary or a tuple of tuple. Logically the tuple should be faster but i might be wrong

Comment: A tuple should be faster and use less memory.

Comment: I suspect the speed/memory difference will be minimal, certainly not worth worrying about in the vast majority of circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says "or an iterable of key/value pairs (as tuples or other iterables of length two)".

Therefore you need to pass it a tuple of tuples that have length 2

Try this:

```
dict1.update((("stat",10),))
```

Or you can pass multiple key/value pairs as followings:

```
dict1.update((("stat",10), ('foo', 'bar'), ('buzz', 'fizz')))
```

Comment: It is weird that it doesn't work with only one tuple.

Comment: So a single 2-length tuple would never work? This is problematic since I have to add each value one-by-one as I am in a loop.

Comment: Afaik, it will only work this way. I found another thread that explains the same thing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11746698/1331040

Comment: With one tuple, you need to put a comma after it: `dict1.update((("stat",10),))`

Comment: @sabik Thanks for the clarification. I just wanted to show the concept of passing tuple of tuples by passing it multiple pairs.

Answer (score 0):

Add a , to the tuple end `dict1.update((("stat",10),))`
Or pass a list `dict1.update([("stat",10)])`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

`dict1.update({"stat": 10})`